# How to perform Image processing in Android without an API?

Tags: android, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm planning to write an app for Android which performs a simple cell counting. The method I'm planning to use is a type of Blob analysis.

The steps of my procedure would be;

1. Histographing to identify the threshold values to perform the thresholding.
2. Thresholding to create a binary image where cells are white and the background is black.
3. Filtering to remove noise and excess particles.
4. Particle (blob) analysis to count cells.

I got this sequence from [this site](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/3169) where functions from the software IMAQ Vision are used to perform those steps.

I'm aware that on Android I can use OpenCV's similar functions to replicate the above procedure. But I would like to know whether I'd be able to implement histographing, thresholding and Blob analysis myself writing the required algorithms without calling API functions. Is that possible? And how hard would it be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. From a PNG image (e.g. from disk or camera), you can generate a Bitmap object. The Bitmap gives you direct access to the pixel color values. You can also create new Bitmap objects based on raw data.

Then it is up to you to implement the algorithms. Creating a histogram and thresholding  should be easy, filtering and blob analysis more difficult. It depends on your exposure to algorithms and data structures, however a hands-on approach is not bad either.

Just make sure to downscale large images (Bitmap can do that too). This saves memory (which can be critical on Android) and gives better results.